# JSON Data handling issue

Tags: objective-c, json, ios8

```
 [manager POST:@"myurl here" parameters:param success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
            NSLog(@"Response %@", responseObject);


if ([responseObject[@"code"]isEqualToString: @"202"] )
            {

               totalorders = responseObject[@"orders"];
                for (int i= 0 ; i< [totalorders count]; i++)
                {
                    dataDictionary =[[totalorders objectAtIndex:i]objectForKey:@"odate"];


                    [dates addObject:[dataDictionary objectForKey:@"odate"]];

                    NSLog(@"%@",dataDictionary );


                }


            }
```

I have tried this as well

```
dates addobject: [dataDictionary allValues];
```

I am what i log is dates, now here i am unable to store data in from `datadictionary` to `NSarray`
need help.
Thanks
I have to show data in tableview later on..
 kindly provide me some link to **JSON Parsing** basics

```
<br><br> My Output is 2015-01-15 16:56:54.851 Test Application [4245:474718] 2015-01-12
2015-01-15 16:56:54.851 Test Application[4245:474718] 2015-01-08
2015-01-15 16:56:54.852 Test Application[4245:474718] 2015-01-08
2015-01-15 16:56:54.852 Test Application[4245:474718] 2015-01-05
2015-01-15 16:56:54.852 Test Application[4245:474718] 2015-01-05
2015-01-15 16:56:54.853 Test Application[4245:474718] 2015-01-05
2015-01-15 16:56:54.853 Test Application[4245:474718] 2015-01-05
2015-01-15 16:56:54.854 Test Application[4245:474718] 2015-01-05
2015-01-15 16:56:54.855 Test Application[4245:474718] 2015-01-05
2015-01-15 16:56:54.855 Test Application[4245:474718] 2015-01-05
2015-01-15 16:56:54.855 Test Application[4245:474718] 2015-01-05
2015-01-15 16:56:54.856 Test Application[4245:474718] 2015-01-05
2015-01-15 16:56:54.858 Test Application[4245:474718] 2015-01-05
2015-01-15 16:56:54.858 Test Application[4245:474718] 2015-01-05
2015-01-15 16:56:54.859 Test Application[4245:474718] 2015-01-05
2015-01-15 16:56:54.859 Test Application[4245:474718] 2015-01-05
2015-01-15 16:56:54.859 Test Application[4245:474718] 2015-01-05
2015-01-15 16:56:54.860 Test Application[4245:474718] 2015-01-05
2015-01-15 16:56:54.860 Test Application[4245:474718] 2015-01-05
2015-01-15 16:56:54.861 Test Application[4245:474718] 2015-01-02
2015-01-15 16:56:54.861 Test Application[4245:474718] 2014-11-25
2015-01-15 16:56:54.861 Test Application[4245:474718] 2014-11-25
2015-01-15 16:56:54.862 Test Application[4245:474718] 2014-11-25
2015-01-15 16:56:54.862 Test Application[4245:474718] 2014-11-25
2015-01-15 16:56:54.863 Test Application[4245:474718] 2014-11-17
2015-01-15 16:56:54.863 Test Application[4245:474718] 2014-11-17
2015-01-15 16:56:54.866 Test Application[4245:474718] 2014-11-17
2015-01-15 16:56:54.867 Test Application[4245:474718] 2014-11-13
2015-01-15 16:56:54.867 Test Application[4245:474718] 2014-11-13
2015-01-15 16:56:54.868 Test Application[4245:474718] 2014-11-13
2015-01-15 16:56:54.868 Test Application[4245:474718] 2014-11-13
2015-01-15 16:56:54.868 Test Application[4245:474718] 2014-11-13
2015-01-15 16:56:54.869 Test Application[4245:474718] 2014-11-13
2015-01-15 16:56:54.869 Test Application[4245:474718] 2014-11-12
2015-01-15 16:56:54.870 Test Application[4245:474718] 2014-11-12
2015-01-15 16:56:54.870 Test Application[4245:474718] 2014-11-10
2015-01-15 16:56:54.871 Test Application[4245:474718] 2014-11-10
2015-01-15 16:56:54.871 Test Application[4245:474718] 2014-11-10
2015-01-15 16:56:54.871 Test Application[4245:474718] 2014-11-10
2015-01-15 16:56:54.872 Test Application[4245:474718] 2014-11-06
2015-01-15 16:56:54.872 Test Application[4245:474718] 2014-11-05
2015-01-15 16:56:54.874 Test Application[4245:474718] 2014-11-05
2015-01-15 16:56:54.874 Test Application[4245:474718] 2014-11-05
2015-01-15 16:56:54.875 Test Application[4245:474718] 2014-11-05
```

Comment: post the code which get you 'responseObject'

Comment: i am using AFNEtworking

Comment: Post what you receive in responseObject and what you want to show in table view because I can't understand what is 'odate' and what object it is (NSDictionary or NSArray).

Comment: now i need to show dates on the very right side of output in tableview cells

Comment: I have created the array named dates which will show data in tableview cell

Comment: I have updated my Question please check this out..

Comment: Without seeing your JSON it's hard to tell you much of anything, though it appears that what you call `dataDictionary` is actually a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have correctly drilled down to date object with the below line  of code

```
[[totalorders objectAtIndex:i]objectForKey:@"odate"]
```

so it is unnecessary to get object again for the same key

further you might get crash when you try to add nil object to array But surprised to see that's not so you may not have allocated the 'dates' array

And below is the code with fixed issues

```
dates=[NSMutableArray new];
if ([responseObject[@"code"]isEqualToString: @"202"] )
            {

               totalorders = responseObject[@"orders"];
                for (int i= 0 ; i< [totalorders count]; i++)
                {
                    dataDictionary =[[totalorders objectAtIndex:i]objectForKey:@"odate"];


                    [dates addObject:dataDictionary];

                    NSLog(@"dates %@",dates );


                }


            }
```

Note that message sent to nil object won't result in crash but adding a nil object will do

Comment: dates are as follows:  (
    "2015-01-12",
    "2015-01-08",
    "2015-01-08",
    "2015-01-05",
    "2015-01-05",
    "2015-01-05",
    "2015-01-05",
    "2015-01-05",
    "2015-01-05",
    "2015-01-05",
    "2015-01-05",
    "2015-01-05",
    "2015-01-05",
    "2015-01-05",
    "2015-01-05",
    "2015-01-05",
    "2015-01-05",
    "2015-01-05",
    "2015-01-05",
    "2015-01-02",
    "2014-11-25",
    "2014-11-25",
    "2014-11-06",
    "2014-11-05",
    "2014-11-05",
    "2014-11-05",
    "2014-11-05"
)
 this is my output. this is not a correct format of array, how can i do this??

Comment: [@"2015-01-12",@"2015-01-12",@"2015-01-12",@"2015-01-12",@"2015-01-12",nil];

Comment: It is just console representation of NSArray.Just representation. dates actually contain array of date strings